# What is Lebesgue measure of sets of inverse prime numbers in $[0,1] $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inverse, lebesgue-measure, prime-gaps

I would like to know if it is possible to know the **Lebesgue mesure** of 
sets of inverse prime numbers in $[0,1]$.

**Note** : I think I should know first whether the sets of primes are infinite countable or uncountable according to the large gaps and short gaps between primes .

Comment: You mean the reciprocals of the primes? Any countable set has zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: ok, are the sets of primes countable ?

Comment: Yes; it's a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so there is an injection to $\mathbb{N}$ through the inclusion map. There being an injection to $\mathbb{N}$ is the definition of countability.

Comment: Then sorry for my question